# Compiled classes with resources as library project?

Tags: android, android-build, android-maven-plugin

I have to develop an Android library which needs to be packaged and distributed to Android developers. It has **both** Java classes and resources (icons etc).

I'm wondering about the best way of distributing such a library. As we all know many well-known libraries are distributed in different formats:

- ActionBAr Sherlock - ZIP or APKLIB
- Flurry - JAR

My Prerequisites:

1. I can't distribute sources - only compiled java classes and resources are allowed
2. My aim is to have integration with client project instruction as simple as possible - e.g. one line in Maven/Gradle as dependency and few lines of code how to use it within the app.
3. I have to respect every build system: those using NBS, those using android-maven-plugin and those using legacy ANT.

My first idea was to distribute this library as APKLIB (Maven) and AAR (NBS) but then I realized no support for ANT.

Questions:

1. Can APKLIB and AAR have only compiled classes and resources instead of plain Java sources?
2. How to distribute a compiled android library project for ANT? As a ZIP?
3. What about generating R for libraries?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: "How to distribute a compiled android library project for ANT? As a ZIP?" -- yes. Create a regular Android library project and get it working. Then, clone the Android library project directory and replace the `src/` tree with a JAR in `libs/`, where the JAR contains the classes compiled with your original library project (optionally with manual ProGuard-ing). You will still need an empty `src/` directory, last I checked, or the traditional build system will choke. ZIP up the cloned library project, and that's your distribution. The Play Services SDK is pretty much distributed this way AFAICT.

Answer (score 2):

1. An [APKLIB](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib) is only supposed to contain sources, libs and resources, *not* the compiled `.class` files. Complementary, the [AAR format](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format) is "the binary distribution of an Android Library Project" and must contain `classes.jar`, but *no* sources.
   **Edit:** However, there is a trick that you can use for an APKLIB to contain compiled classes instead of source code: Compile the source code and put it at `libs/<library-name>.jar` inside the APKLIB instead of the `bin` directory. Then replace all files in `src` with some dummy file.
2. You can distribute a compiled Android Library Project for Ant as an AAR, but you have to keep a few things in mind when using it. Ant explicitly looks for the `src` directory in the extracted AAR file, but there is none, and Ant looks for `classes.jar` in the `bin` directory, but it is located at the root of the extracted AAR file. You can work around this by creating an empty `src` directory and copying `classes.jar` to `bin/classes.jar`. That is exactly what we do in an Ivy `post-retrieve-artifact` step after retrieving the AAR artifact. **Edit:** This has the disadvantage that `ant clean` will delete the `bin/classes.jar`, and you're probably better off with using an APKLIB with a `jar` packaged as part of the `libs` directory as described above.
3. Neither APKLIB nor AAR are not supposed to come with a compiled `R` class, both ship with their original resources in the `res` directory. Additionally, an AAR has to contain an `R.txt` file listing all the resources (as output by `aapt --output-text-symbols`).